# Shortening If/Else from if(x == y || x == z) to if(x == y || z) in swift

Tags: swift

I'm making an app where I have to put a lot of `if/else` statements. I know you can do as in the title in some other coding language, but I'm not sure if you can do it in Swift.

How do you shorten this:

```
if x == y || x == z {
    //do something
}
```

To something like this:

```
if x == y || z {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Which other languages, out of interest?

Comment: @Bathsheba Tbh I don't remember, but I remember doing it, just not how.

Comment: In C, C++, and Java, the two forms are different.

Comment: It has been either C# or Javascript as those are the ones I've been working with other than Swift.

Comment: @Bathsheba I guess it was Javascript then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I conject that there is no sensible language (swift included), that *distributes* comparison `==` *across* logical or `||`.

The way you've written it - `x == y || x == z` - is the most compact form.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you could consider using an array and checking to see if `x` is in the array, like in the following example:

```
let (x, y, z) = (3, 8, 3)

if [y, z].contains(x) {
    //True
}
```

If you're comparing objects (like `UIImage`), use `containsObject` instead of `contains`:

```
if [x, y, z].containsObject(y) {
    //True
}
```

Comment: Yup, was just trying to find this. I think this is the best solution.

Comment: @Jack Greenhill - I just tried to do it this way, however it doesn't seem to work properly with UIImages.

`if imageArray.contains(tile11.currentImage) {
            
        }`

Comment: @StevoHN See my updated answer on how to compare objects

Answer (score 3):

[Jack Greenhill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33757711/3443689) does indeed go into the right direction. However with more and more values, his method will get very inefficient, since it has to check every element of the array against equality, therefore complexity `O(n)`.

A very underrated data structure, which can do this kind of operation in `O(1)` should be used instead: The Set. It uses hash values to check quickly whether a value is present or not. You can use it like this:

```
let x = 3
let values : Set = [1, 3, 6, 1, 7]    // {6, 7, 3, 1}

if values.contains(x) {
    // ...
}
```

This takes the same amount of time, whether `values` contains just one or 1000 elements. An array would be 1000 times slower.

Oftentimes the decision to use an array is made before even considering a set. If your elements don't have any order and can only occur once (which is actually more often the case than you'd think), you probably want a set. A set gives you useful methods, such as `union`, `isSubset`, `interception` and more, for free by just putting your elements in it. The only additional requirement for the element type is to conform to `Hashable`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
switch x {
case y, z : // do then
default   : // do else
}
```