# Swift if case with logical OR

Tags: swift

Say we have an enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
  case foo(Int)
  case bar
}
```

and we can do something like this:

```
func myFunc(_ foo: MyEnum, _ bar: MyEnum) {
  if case .foo(_) = foo, case .bar = bar {...}
}
```

but what if I need some like this

```
if case .foo(_) = foo, case .bar = bar OR someVar == true {...}
```

where I want either `case .foo(_) = foo, case .bar = bar` to be true, or `someVar` to be true.

Apparently I can't put `||` there, and I couldn't figure out an alternative. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: so, in your thinking... what are the _left_ and _right_ arguments of the `||` (OR) operand here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to abbreviate this condition in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706702/is-it-possible-to-abbreviate-this-condition-in-swift)

Comment: @holex: I edited the question to be more specific

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor, I disagree it is a duplicate of the question you pointed out. I am not trying to abbreviating anything, and I still couldn't think of a way of doing the OR after reading that question.

Comment: @holex: you made me thinking, what if I want either `case .foo(_) = foo` to be true, or `case .bar = bar OR someVar == true` to be true?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is possible with a single if statement. However, you could use a switch statement like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case foo(Int)
    case bar
}

func myFunc(_ foo: MyEnum, _ bar: MyEnum, _ someVar: Bool) {
    switch (foo, bar, someVar) {
    case (.foo, .bar, _), (_, _, true):
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @tonisuter, that would work. But it's a bit odd to not be able to use a `if` statement in such case.